# numpy.array does not convert my list of lists into 2d numpy array in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists

This is the list of lists I have

```
[[3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1], [1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4],....,[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2], [3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3], [3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4], [4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]]
```

I tried numpy.array but it gives a 1D array like this

```
[[3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1] [3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4] [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1] ...,
 [4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3] [3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4] [4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]]
```

whose size is (15410,) which means it's not being created as 2D.

I even tried using np.vstack and np.concatenate. But it says all lists must be of the same dimension. They are all of the same length. I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I am using python3. Also is there a better way to convert a list of lists to a 2D numpy array?

Edit: The code that converts the list of lists to numpy array:

```
      print(testFeature)
      x_test=np.array(testFeature)
      print(x_test)
      print (x_test.shape)
```

Comment: –1 can not reproduce

Comment: What did you try? Some actual code would be nice.

Comment: That looks like a 2D Python list, or perhaps a Numpy array of lists. How can we suggest a better way to convert a list of lists to a 2D Numpy array when you haven't shown us the way that you used?

Comment: Is this 1d array `dtype` object?  If `vstack` complains about the length of the lists, I trust it, not your assertion.  All the errors indicate that one or more of the lists is different.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried printing the length of each list as I created it. All of them were 7

Comment: @LukasR I have updated with what I tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you list is called l, the code below should help you find the offending elements.

```
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    if(len(v)!=len(l[0])):
        print('bad element {} at {}'.format(v,i))
```

Fixing these elements should help fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The size field of a numpy array is the total number of elements in it. The 2D structure of the array you are looking for is accessed via the 'shape' field.

EDIT: 
Have you noticed that your sublists are (apparently) of length 7, but 15410 is not a multiple of 7 ? That means your sublists cannot be all of the same length, which is consistent with the error you get from np.vstack

Comment: Though ` (15410,)` looks like a `shape` tuple.  He might just be using the terms shape/size loosely.  The `vstack` error supports this 1d reading.

Comment: @hpaulj excellent point there. I update my answer with another argument I just noticed

Comment: 15410 is the number of lists. Each list has 7 elements. So the size should be (15410,7) but it's not recognizing the second dimension. My problem is I want it to be a 2D array. That's what I'm seeking help for.